# S5 G901f 4G+ on Android 6 is slow to switch tower

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, samsung-galaxy-s-5, mobile-network

My recently purchased Samsung GS5 G901f 4G+ on Android 6 loses network for ~10s in many locations. I have used the "Open Signal" app to get an understanding of the problem. It seems to me like the S5 is not properly switching to a different tower when I walk around. It lets the reception get really low, the connection cuts, and after ~10s of having no network it will finally connect to another antenna. I know there is something wrong with the phone because with the same carrier+SIM card I never lose network in my area on my old S4.

So my question is, is this a software problem or could it be hardware?

Comment: Probably hardware, since it sounds like the radio is damaged or limited somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a software problem. Switching to android 5 fixed the issue.